# How to install Laravel in a subfolder near a CakePHP install

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, laravel

I have a CakePHP app at domain.com and wish to also have a Laravel app there in a subfolder, at domain.com/laravel.

The top-level .htaccess file looks, for CakePHP's purposes, like:

> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
> RewriteRule    (.*)
> app/webroot/$1 [L]
>
> </IfModule>

I tried to insert a line above those two RewriteRules something like:

> RewriteRule ^laravel/(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]

Which may be working as far as it goes, but now when I look at domain.com/laravel I see only a white screen.

I have granted permissions to Laravel's app/storage and done everything else I can think of that would normally get things up and running. What am I missing?

ETA: Gah! And of course all the above was (probably) fine. Apache was trying to use PHP 5.3 and falling foul of the new [] array syntax at pretty much the first hurdle. Got everything running under 5.4, but am now getting a Laravel Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException.  So there may still be work to be done...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running Apache, why not just create two virtual hosts and keep them entirely separate. You can name them domain.com/cakeapp and domain.com/laravelapp but the directories they reside in will be completely unrelated.

Comment: Seems like the correct approach, this is on Dreamhost though and I don't think they give direct access. There's probably a way of making it happen through their panel mind you.

Comment: Grr, I have domain.com/laravelapp correctly showing the Laravel "you have arrived" page, but domain.com/laravelapp/1 is showing me a Cake address not found error... getting close though.